# How to split text into sentences and create a new dataframe with one sentence per row?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, text-processing

I have a dataframe `df` that has 3 columns containing speechdata: `filename`, `president`, `text`.

I split the text data into sentences using:

```
# Split 'text' column into sentences and create a new 'sentences' column
df['sentences'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: nltk.sent_tokenize(x))
```

However, this code tokenizes the text in such a way, that the split text is still in one row in the 'sentences' column.
I want to create a new dataframe named 'data_sentence' that contains the split sentences and their respective filename, president but with each row containing ONE sentence.

```
data_sentence = pd.DataFrame(columns=['filename', 'president', 'sentnew'])

# Iterate over each row in the original DataFrame 'df'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    filename = row['filename']
    president = row['president']
    sentences = row['sentences']
    
    # Create a temporary DataFrame for the sentences of the current row
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': [filename] * len(sentences),
                            'president': [president] * len(sentences),
                            'sentnew': sentences})
    
    # Concatenate the temporary DataFrame with 'data_sentence'
    data_sentence = pd.concat([data_sentence, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

# Print the resulting DataFrame 'data_sentence'
print(data_sentence)
```

this code works but does not assign ONE sentence to ONE row.

can someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the *sentences* :

```
df['sentences'] = df.pop('text').apply(lambda x: nltk.sent_tokenize(x)) # use `df.pop`

data_sentence = df.explode('sentences') # <-- add this line
```

Output :

| filename | president | sentences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file1.txt | A | How to split text into sentences and create a new dataframe with one sentence per row using NLTK and Pandas? |
| file1.txt | A | I have a dataframe df that has 3 columns containing speechdata: 'filename', 'president', 'text'. |

*Input used :*

```
import nltk
nltk.download("punkt")

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "filename": ["file1.txt"],
    "president": ["A"],
    "text": [
        "How to split text into sentences and create a new dataframe "
        "with one sentence per row using NLTK and Pandas? "
        "I have a dataframe df that has 3 columns containing "
        "speechdata: 'filename', 'president', 'text'.",
    ]
})
```

Comment: after entering your code from above with the given input my dataframe still is a 1x3 df

Comment: No, the code works fine (*see* https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2U1.png). You said in your post that you need a new DataFrame. My code creates one for you : It is `data_sentence`.  If you need to overwrite the original one, use `df = df.explode('sentences')`.